# Copy file from server to two target disks

Tags: cpu, load

After I rescue some disk, I copy the result (disk image of several TBs ) from local network data storage (LNDS) to target disk as a file. Usualy the filesystem of the target disk is NTFS. The LNDS is capable to pass data to me at the speed > 600MB/s (on 10Gbit network).
The target disk is capable to save data at sustain speed >150 MB/s. But the speed of copying file from the server to target disk filesystem is damned slower, etwa 60-80MB/s.
Today I was asked to prepare two copy. Well, I used the tee command to specify two targets:

```
dd if=/servermount/path/file.img bs=8192 |tee /localmount/target1/file.img >/localmount/target2/file.img
```

(`cp` cannot be forked with `tee`) But what surprized me: the copy speed is about 40MB/s only.
I immediately started to analyse the trafic: The network is loading data at the sustained speed of 40MB/s, and both disks writes at max speed 160MB/s but less then 25% of the time.

I have looked the `top` and found that the CPU spends most time with two `mount.ntfs` processes - each takes >40% - and `tee` which takes about 30% of CPU time.

I tried also a revers process: I started a samba server on my workstation, added the two targets as share, and sended the data from server to the two disks.
I was surprised again, because the common speed has grown to 66 - 69 MB/s and the mount.ntfs processes were spending just about 7% CPU time.

I cannot understand, why there was such great difference between push and pull over the net, and other way than it could be expected.

Not all bash command are suitable for piping with `tee`. The `dd` if targeted to `/dev/null` gives the speed of 650-700MB/s. If I copy the physical disk to two other phys. disks (no metter if making clones or creating two disk images) the copy speed is over 120MB/s, and the same I get if the target is on the server (LNDS).

Can some body explain me, what I did wrong. Is there some copy command more suitable for copying large file from LNDS to two local disks?

Answer (score 0):

I tried some hints I found on the Internet:

I is recomended to mount NTFS with option: `big_writes`. I can admit, it can realy decrease the CPU load from 40% to 5-7%.
But the main question, why the formerly shown `dd` command has throuput less than 40 MB/s, this question still reamins.

The next hint was to use two independent processes simultaneously to copy the source to first target, and the same source to the second target something like:

```
# (cp /servermount/path/file.img /localmount/target1/)& 
# (cp /servermount/path/file.img /localmount/target2/)&
```

This could be send from two consoles or from a single by use of backrounding the processes.

I was surprised, that the network sustained speed was above 110MB/s and the writes to both disks were nearly synchronous at the speed over 170MB/s with dutycycle about 50-70%.

Well, I found some solution. It may be a good feature that OS has such good disk buffer management, to be able to "think creatively for us", but on the other hand, I cannot understand the OS's behavior that is in direct oposition to reasonable expectations. Even if the same `dd` command sourced from pysical disk works perfectly.

I hope I will not be punished again for silently expressing my opinion.